How do I specify continuous/categorical features to the model?
I have a dataset with 90 categorical features and 10 continuous features. All columns are integers, and I use VectorAssembler as the sole preprocessing step - this is a saved intermediate which needs no further treatment from StringIndexer, StandardScaler, etc. When I try to fit a DecisionTreeClassifier, I get the following message:
IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: DecisionTree requires maxBins (= 32) to be at least as large as the number of values in each categorical feature, but categorical feature 91 has 100 values. Consider removing this and other categorical features with a large number of values, or add more training examples.

How can I specify to the model or to VectorAssembler which fields are continuous and which are categorical?
